# How to separate string to two side and auto delete number zero in PHP?

Tags: php, string, csv

I'm building importing feature from CSV format and insert value into DB But I got some problem when I want to change the code format as bellow.

I have some Invoice code format as below code but i want to separate other another code format

```
IP14010459
DEP14010460
IP14010461
DEP14010462
ISP14010462
ISP14010463
ISP14010464
ISP14010465
ISP14010466
ISP14010466
ISP14010467
```

I'm going to change the code format to

```
IP1401-459 (Zero has been deleted)
DEP1401-460 (Zero has been deleted)
IP1401-461 (Zero has been deleted)
DEP1401-462 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-462 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-463 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-464 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-465 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-466 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-466 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-467 (Zero has been deleted)
```

And I'm also delete number 0 of prefix (If have) of right side of code format
How can i do this friend.

Comment: Are these invoice values fixed-length? or will they expand over time as you exceed 999 or 9999?

Comment: It will not fixed length after the invoice increase number will change from 999 to 9999 or 99999 but I just need the way to separate only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

```
$str = "IP14010461";  //DEP14010462

echo substr_replace($str, '-', -4, 1);
```

Output:

```
IP1401-461  //DEP1401-462
```

---

```
$str = "IP14010461";
// $str = "DEP14010462";
echo substr_replace($str, '-', -4, 1) . "  (Zero has been deleted)";
```

---

#### When using a file, which is useful for a batch process:

```
if (($handle = fopen("1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);    
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {            

echo substr_replace($data[$c], '-', -4, 1) . "  (Zero has been deleted)";

            echo "<br />";  
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Output:

```
IP1401-459 (Zero has been deleted)
DEP1401-460 (Zero has been deleted)
IP1401-461 (Zero has been deleted)
DEP1401-462 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-462 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-463 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-464 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-465 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-466 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-466 (Zero has been deleted)
ISP1401-467 (Zero has been deleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file named 1.csv with your info inside:

```
IP14010459
DEP14010460
IP14010461
DEP14010462
ISP14010462
ISP14010463
ISP14010464
ISP14010465
ISP14010466
ISP14010466
ISP14010467
```

You can do this:

```
<?php

$strings = file('1.csv');

for($i = 0; $i < count($strings); $i++) {
echo substr(trim($strings[$i]), 0, -4) . '-' . substr(trim($strings[$i]), -3) . ' (Zero has been deleted)' . "<br/>\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks let me test it

Comment: @trueman if this solved your problem don't forget check as correct

Comment: preg_replace("/(\D+\d{4})0*([1-9]+\d*)/i","$1-$2\n", "ISP14010462")
This sentence and escape all 0 and although I increase or discrease some character of left and right it will keep the same format. this is good for me to using it for importing from excel because I have already used loop ready

Answer (score 0):

With preg_replace

```
echo preg_replace("/(\D+\d{4})0*([1-9]+\d*)/i","$1-$2\n", "ISP14010462"); 

ISP1401-462
```

This take all letter and 4 digit, remove 0 and keep other digit

Comment: @trueman I don't get the meaning of your comment. (Sorry for my english)